# Combine multiple aggregate queries into one insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a database with timeseries data and I've got 4 different queries that I'm trying to mash together to form a set of data for a single insert.

```
SELECT 'some date' AS date, a, b, COUNT(foo) AS c
FROM 'my_db'
WHERE date BETWEEN dateadd(hour,-24,'some date') AND dateadd(hour,-23,'some date')
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a, b ASC;


SELECT a, b, COUNT(foo) AS c1
FROM 'my_db'
WHERE (date BETWEEN dateadd(hour,-24,'some date') AND dateadd(hour,-23,'some date'))
    AND (foo = 'some value')
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a, b ASC;


SELECT a, b, COUNT(foo) AS c2
FROM 'my_db'
WHERE (date BETWEEN dateadd(hour,-24,'some date') AND dateadd(hour,-23,'some date'))
    AND (foo = 'some other value')
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a, b ASC;
```

If these were in separate tables, I feel like I'd be able to individually do full outer joins on fields `a` and `b`, then just fill the empty fields with 0s.

And by the end, I'd be able to get to the dataset to look like this for a single insert :

```
|         date        |   a   |   b   |   c   |   c1    |    c2    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2019-08-27 12:00:00 |  dog  |  woof |  100  |   76    |    26    |
| 2019-08-27 12:00:00 |  cat  |  meow |   82  |   33    |    49    |
| 2019-08-27 12:00:00 | pony  | neigh |  300  |    0    |   300    |
```

Is there a clean way to combine these queries into one so that I can bulk insert the formatted set?

Or is there a smarter way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 'some date' AS date, a, b, COUNT(foo) AS c,
       SUM(CASE WHEN foo = 'some value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as c1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN foo = 'some other value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as c2
FROM 'my_db'
WHERE date BETWEEN dateadd(hour, -24, 'some date') AND dateadd(hour, -23, 'some date')
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a, b ASC;
```